# Coderbyte Array Addition Solution -- For Loop with a For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to understand the logic in a solution to the Array Addition CoderByte problem. Here is the question prompt -- "Using the JavaScript language, have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers."

This is a solution that works, but I get lost with the for loop within the for loop. Why isn't it always the case that i = j since the for loops both start with their counters at 0. So wouldn't it always be 0 = 0?

```
  function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b})
  var largest = arr.pop();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      if (i != j) {
        sum += arr[j];
        if (sum == largest) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
      if (i != k) {
        sum -= arr[k];
        if (sum == largest) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    sum = 0;
  }
  // code goes here  
  return false; 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The full `j` loop gets run on every iteration of the `i` loop.

Comment: Cuberto, thanks for responding. I'm still lost. If the j loop is running each iteration of the i loop, isn't it always the case that the line sum += arr[j] doens't matter sense if(i != j) is always the case?

Comment: No, it's not always the case. On the first time, `i` and `j` are both 0. Then `i` is 0 but `j` is 1. Then `i` is 0 but `j` is 2. Etc...

Comment: But why the 'k' loop?  Pretty sure this will work without it, right?

Answer (score 0):

i_made_that & user3085131:

To further explain the k loop, it is used to work back through and subtract array values in the order that they were initially added, to yield new results not otherwise obtainable.

Without the k loop you can't solve many potential arrays (although it will actually pass the coderbyte test cases due to lack of appropriate test).

Consider [1,2,3,98,100]...this should pass since 2+98 = 100. However it won't without the k loop. If you log the results of sum without the k, you would see:

```
3 (1 + 2)
6 (3 + 3) 
104 (6 + 98) 
3 (2 + 1) 
6 (3 + 3) 
104 (6 + 98) 
4 (3 + 1) 
6 (4 + 2) 
104 (6 + 98) 
99 (98 + 1) 
101 (99 + 2) 
104 (101 + 3)
```

With the k loop however, on the second iteration of i it will pass as it will subtract 1 from 104, and then 3 from 103 to reach 100.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, is that you have 2 **for** loops inside the **for** loop with the "i" variable. 
variable  "i"  is always going to be 0 until you finish iterating thru the 2 for loops that are inside.

```js
for(var i=0){
  
  for(var j=0){}
  
  for(var k=0){}
  
  }
```